# Python tkinter: a scrollable list with text and images?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using python 2.7 and I'd like to have an GUI with a scrollable list where each item in the list has both an image and some text. I'd like these items to be selectable like in a ListBox. I've tried a couple things and it seems ListBox only accepts text?

What widget/combination of widgets should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing a whole bunch of buttons in a frame and assigning a scroll bar a to that frame and make it so when the user presses a button is changes colour or picture or something and then any button with that same colour of picture before will go back to normal. Also, and a tkinter variable with which button is active so you can reference it later.

I'm fairly sure you can use both texts and images in a button simultaneously, but if not you can just put a button and an image side by side in the same row on the frame

I recommend you make this entire scrolling object a class and keep references of everything inside within that class.

If you need any help doing this, just give me a shout.